# Android OpenGL ES Map Globe Like WhirlyGlobe in iOS

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, dictionary, 3d

I need to make a Globe Map in android like [this](http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/), i tried to search alot but found no helping results it's somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766799/spinning-globe-in-opengl-es) question, can any one help me out How should i implement it in android.

[image]

Touch Rotate

[image]

Need to have a Globe Like this with Markers and on Tap display info and perform task.

[image]

Can any one provide me some steps on how should i proceed to get the Globe running in my android app.
I have no idea where to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Basic globe and texture should not be a big deal. To add clickable markers, you could use other gl-objects (planes?). Add them at desired place. To make this objects clickable, ray intersection could be a way.
I suggest using a 3D-framework which provides object picking instead of doing it all by yourself. Have a look at Rajawali (object picking)

http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/

and/or Min3d

http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2010/05/17/loading-3d-models-with-the-min3d-framework-for-android/